# Shared Access and LG Smart TV 766PA?

Tags: sharing, rename

The Videos directory contains files 1.mkv 2.mkv and so on. When trying to share them inside the local network on LG 766PA, the file names become very strange, not the ones I did. Instead of 1.mkv, another name appears altogether. How can this be fixed?
Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

It's all because of the mkv file itself. To display normal names (or at least start with a human-understandable word), you must do

```
mkvpropedit "1.mkv" -s title="1 episode"
```